# How to make the svg icon in a 'a' tag be always on the left part and the text stay middle in the rest part?

Tags: css, svg

Here is my HTML and CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/o63kxtrj/

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" title="example" class="again"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="24" viewBox="0 0 20 24" style=""><path style="fill=#339966" d="M 17.1 6.75Q 16.0314453125 5.6814453125 14.8 5 12.646875 3.8 10 3.8L 10 0 1.75 4.95 1.8 5 10 10 10 6.2Q 11.6 6.2 12.9 6.75 14.25 7.35 15.4 8.45 17.2 10.3 17.55 12.8 17.6 13.3 17.6 13.85 17.6 17 15.4 19.2 13.15 21.45 10 21.45 6.85 21.45 4.65 19.2 2.4 17 2.4 13.85L 0 13.85Q 0 18 2.95 20.9 5.85 23.85 10 23.85 12.65 23.85 14.8 22.65 16 22 17.1 20.9 17.7 20.3 18.15 19.65 20 17.1 20 13.85 20 13.4 19.95 12.95 19.7 9.5 17.3 6.95 17.2 6.85 17.1 6.75 Z"></path>Retry</svg></a>
```

CSS:

```
.again {
    display: block;
    width: 65%;
    margin: 55px auto 0;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    color: #333;
    text-align:center;
}
```

It seems svg is not like an `img` tag, it's eating my text "Retry". And I want to know how to make it working like this (not exactly the same icon but I think it explains well what I desire):

[image]

Comment: Put `Retry` text after svg tag, not inside

Answer (score 2):

Put Retry text after `</svg>` tag, not inside

Try

```css
.again {
    display: block;
    width: 65%;
    margin: 55px auto 0;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    color: #333;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}
.again svg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com" title="example" class="again"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="24" viewBox="0 0 20 24" style=""><path style="fill=#339966" d="M 17.1 6.75Q 16.0314453125 5.6814453125 14.8 5 12.646875 3.8 10 3.8L 10 0 1.75 4.95 1.8 5 10 10 10 6.2Q 11.6 6.2 12.9 6.75 14.25 7.35 15.4 8.45 17.2 10.3 17.55 12.8 17.6 13.3 17.6 13.85 17.6 17 15.4 19.2 13.15 21.45 10 21.45 6.85 21.45 4.65 19.2 2.4 17 2.4 13.85L 0 13.85Q 0 18 2.95 20.9 5.85 23.85 10 23.85 12.65 23.85 14.8 22.65 16 22 17.1 20.9 17.7 20.3 18.15 19.65 20 17.1 20 13.85 20 13.4 19.95 12.95 19.7 9.5 17.3 6.95 17.2 6.85 17.1 6.75 Z"></path></svg>Retry</a>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/o63kxtrj/1/)

**Edit:**

```css
.again {
  display: table;
  width: 65%;
  margin: 55px auto 0;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com" title="example" class="again">
  <div class="cell">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="24" viewBox="0 0 20 24" style="">
      <path style="fill=#339966" d="M 17.1 6.75Q 16.0314453125 5.6814453125 14.8 5 12.646875 3.8 10 3.8L 10 0 1.75 4.95 1.8 5 10 10 10 6.2Q 11.6 6.2 12.9 6.75 14.25 7.35 15.4 8.45 17.2 10.3 17.55 12.8 17.6 13.3 17.6 13.85 17.6 17 15.4 19.2 13.15 21.45 10 21.45 6.85 21.45 4.65 19.2 2.4 17 2.4 13.85L 0 13.85Q 0 18 2.95 20.9 5.85 23.85 10 23.85 12.65 23.85 14.8 22.65 16 22 17.1 20.9 17.7 20.3 18.15 19.65 20 17.1 20 13.85 20 13.4 19.95 12.95 19.7 9.5 17.3 6.95 17.2 6.85 17.1 6.75 Z"></path>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">What if the text is very long? What if the text is very long? What if the text is very long? What if the text is very long? What if the text is very long? What if the text is very long?</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's a bit to the lower part. How can I make it vertically aligned to the middle without giving a fixed number?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g0jom0jh/ what is the text is very long? how can I make the icon still be positioned in middle vertically?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you add the 'Retry' after the closing tag `</svg>`

something like this

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" title="example" class="again"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="24" viewBox="0 0 20 24" style=""><path style="fill=#339966" d="M 17.1 6.75Q 16.0314453125 5.6814453125 14.8 5 12.646875 3.8 10 3.8L 10 0 1.75 4.95 1.8 5 10 10 10 6.2Q 11.6 6.2 12.9 6.75 14.25 7.35 15.4 8.45 17.2 10.3 17.55 12.8 17.6 13.3 17.6 13.85 17.6 17 15.4 19.2 13.15 21.45 10 21.45 6.85 21.45 4.65 19.2 2.4 17 2.4 13.85L 0 13.85Q 0 18 2.95 20.9 5.85 23.85 10 23.85 12.65 23.85 14.8 22.65 16 22 17.1 20.9 17.7 20.3 18.15 19.65 20 17.1 20 13.85 20 13.4 19.95 12.95 19.7 9.5 17.3 6.95 17.2 6.85 17.1 6.75 Z"></path></svg>Retry</a>
```

and the CSS should be:

```
.again {
    display: block;
    width: 65%;
    margin: 55px auto 0;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    color: #333;
    text-align:center;
}

.again svg{
 float: left;   
}
```

here's a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ohnd1vo6/)

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue is that you just need to move the text out of the  tag.  Than you can just style the svg to move it to the right place.  I've updated your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/z6xgLc3a/.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" title="example" class="again"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="24" viewBox="0 0 20 24" class="icon"><path style="fill=#339966" d="M 17.1 6.75Q 16.0314453125 5.6814453125 14.8 5 12.646875 3.8 10 3.8L 10 0 1.75 4.95 1.8 5 10 10 10 6.2Q 11.6 6.2 12.9 6.75 14.25 7.35 15.4 8.45 17.2 10.3 17.55 12.8 17.6 13.3 17.6 13.85 17.6 17 15.4 19.2 13.15 21.45 10 21.45 6.85 21.45 4.65 19.2 2.4 17 2.4 13.85L 0 13.85Q 0 18 2.95 20.9 5.85 23.85 10 23.85 12.65 23.85 14.8 22.65 16 22 17.1 20.9 17.7 20.3 18.15 19.65 20 17.1 20 13.85 20 13.4 19.95 12.95 19.7 9.5 17.3 6.95 17.2 6.85 17.1 6.75 Z"></path></svg>Retry</a>

.again {
    display: block;
    width: 65%;
    margin: 55px auto 0;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    color: #333;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}

.icon {
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
 top: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that you've declared a left and top value. How can I make it vertically aligned to the middle without giving a fixed number?